# XML parsing by using retrofit 2

Tags: android, xml, retrofit2

I'm having trouble parsing http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml this xml document using retrofits converter.
How would you create the Pojo class for this type of xml document for retrofits xml converter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo class for the xml like this

**Gesmes:Envelope**

```
public class Gesmes:Envelope
{
private Cube Cube;

public Cube getCube ()
{
    return Cube;
}

public void setCube (Cube Cube)
{
    this.Cube = Cube;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [Cube = "+Cube+"]";
}
}
```

**Cube class**

```
public class Cube
{
private String rate;

private String currency;

public String getRate ()
{
    return rate;
}

public void setRate (String rate)
{
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getCurrency ()
{
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency (String currency)
{
    this.currency = currency;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [rate = "+rate+", currency = "+currency+"]";
}
}
```

Comment: This class doesn't contain the time though?